# How to enumerate a list of files

Tags: bash, awk, sh

I want to get a numbered list of files, e.g. if I have these files:

```
a.pdf
b.pdf
c
```

then it should be listed as:

```
1 a.pdf
2 b.pdf
3 c
```

Comment: no need stick on awk command. In fact, for your question, using awk maybe the worse choice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it two ways:-
1st one :-
`ls -1 | awk '{print NR,$0}'`

2nd one:-
`ls -1 | cat -n`
You must prefer 2nd one but choose whatever you like. :-)

Comment: This is matter of fact that who saw the question 1st.If other guyz saw this before me than they will definitely give you answer faster than me.. :-)

Comment: Parsing `ls -l` is almost never a good idea and will break filenames with spaces here.

Comment: @BroSlow yes you are write.

Comment: this accepted awk answer is wrong when file name has space, you'd better to remove it from the answer. it will confuse others.

Comment: No need for the `-1` flag in `ls` : it is the default when you pipe the output to another process.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to [avoid parsing the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) (which you do), you can do something like this:

```
$ counter=1; for f in *; do printf "%2d %s\n" $((counter++)) "$f"; done
 1 a.pdf
 2 b.pdf
 3 c
```

I only mention this because it's the path for doing more sophisticated things, not just enumerating.

Answer (score 8):

If your system has command `nl`, it will be easier. ( I can confirm `nl` command is exist in cygwin, aix and solaris system, then it should be popular command in most unix system)

```
ls |nl
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without awk, trivially. `ls -1 | cat -n`.

Or, with awk:

```
ls -1 | awk '{printf "%d %s\n", NR, $0;}'
```

Comment: Updated, where cat -n is re-implemented in awk.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need to use `awk` but here you go:

```
ls | awk '{print NR, $0}'
```

**updated** `$0` is better than `$1` since it will print the entire file name even with spaces (as hinted at by BroSlow)

Note - you do **not** need to use the `-1` flag with `ls` when the output is another process - it becomes the default option. Only when you want to force output to the terminal with one file per line do you need to use it.

Comment: Because it is said to by awk!!!Thanks it works.But I don't know why I got downpoint in asking question

Comment: Not sure either - but usually downvotes come from "not showing effort". You said you "tried hard" but didn't show your attempt. That, and the fact that this smells like homework although you didn't say so explicitly (otherwise - why on earth do it with awk?), is typically why some people (not me) reach for the down arrow...

Comment: @alfa Exactly what `Floris` said. Also not sure why you accepted the answer you did, its use of `awk` is fairly redundant and will break filenames with spaces.